# Why datum in the pipe in the Bernaulli equation is choosen at the centre of the pipe?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

[image]

Why is the datum taken at the center of the pipe in the Bernaulli's equation? I want to know this to understand if the hole 1 will drain the tank faster or the hole 2. I understand that the time difference will be very small but I need to understand the concept of datum in Bernaulli's equation from this.

[image]